# Python Decimal instances have no `__slots__`, but why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with Python's decimal module, but when I do:

```
>>>from decimal import Decimal
>>>d = Decimal('3.14')
>>>d.__slots__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute '__slots__'
>>>Decimal.__slots__
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'decimal.Decimal' has no attribute '__slots__'
```

But when I inspect `Decimal` class in PyCharm (_pydecimal.py), I see:

```
class Decimal(object):
    """Floating point class for decimal arithmetic."""

    __slots__ = ('_exp','_int','_sign', '_is_special')
...
```

Supposedly, I should be able to get `__slots__` from class/instance, but I didn't. What am I missing here? (This kinda behaves like Python's built-in `int` class.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name.

Comment: @ShaneBishop Can you elaborate why this question is a possible duplicate of naming conventions?

Comment: The answers in that question say that names with a leading double underscore are subjected to python naming mangling, which might explain what was going on. But I'm no python expert, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a particular problem here, or just understanding the implementation?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am just trying to verify that my understanding of `__slots__` and `__dict__` usage in Python is correct, because I was surprised that I was able to use `__dict__` (instead of `__slots__`) to get all attributes of Decimal class for my own class that inherits Decimal.

Comment: @ShaneBishop no, that isn't it

Comment: @vanbastelaer PyCharm is lying to you. `Decimal` is implemented in C. They basically write stubs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `decimal.py`, you'll see this:

```
try:
    from _decimal import *
    from _decimal import __doc__
    from _decimal import __version__
    from _decimal import __libmpdec_version__
except ImportError:
    from _pydecimal import *
    from _pydecimal import __doc__
    from _pydecimal import __version__
    from _pydecimal import __libmpdec_version__
```

It first tries to import from `_decimal`, which is a precompiled shared library on my system. The code you found via PyCharm is instead in the fallback `_pydecimal` implementation. I suspect your code is in fact loading the `_decimal` version of `Decimal`, which simply doesn't use `__slots__`.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. You are probably right. Is there a programmatically way to find out which version (without modifying `decimal.py` to e.g. print something out)? I tried `inspect.getmodule()` but it just gives me `decimal.py`.

Comment: @vanbastelaer. You may be able to do something like inspect the `__name__` or `__module__` attributes of some of the imported classes and functions, not that I expect it will do much good.

Comment: @vanbastelaer if you are using a standard CPython distribution (e.g. from the official installer, from `conda` etc) then you are definitely using the C implemenation